# How to remove keydown event in searchbar of drum website?

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, web, web-deployment-project

I have made drums and assigned a theme to play on the keydown event. I want to add a search bar leading to different pages. But on inputting text inside the search bar audio of the drums is still playing. How do I remove it from that section? Or rather not allow audio to be played in that input element?

Answer (score 0):

If you added the keydown event-listener on an upper(ancestor) element, the keydown event of the input(seachbar) propagates to upper level.

In this case, you might want to use [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop the event from going to upper level.

```js
searchbar.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  ...
})
```